# Assigning variables from a UITableViewCell to be tweeted in main view controller

Tags: ios, variables, twitter, uitableview

I managed to reassign the variables of a UITableViewCell and getting it to tweet with the TWTweetComposeViewController, but I ran into an issue. It's always tweeting the variables from the last row in the UITableView.

Here is my setup: I have 1 tweet button and 4 UILabels in a UITableViewCell. The 4 UILabels are pulling information from a Plist to populate the table. There is a tweet button in every cell to tweet the cell information, but that's where I ran into the issue. **It always tweets the information from the last row in the table instead of the row it's in.** Any help is greatly appreciated.

UITableViewCell.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *playerOneLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *playerOneScoreLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *playerTwoLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *playerTwoScoreLabel;
```

Main View Controller setup:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ScoreListCell";

    ScoreCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    NSDictionary * dictionary = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.playerOneLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerOneName"];
    cell.playerOneScoreLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerOneScore"];
    cell.playerTwoLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerTwoName"];
    cell.playerTwoScoreLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerTwoScore"];

    self.player1Name = cell.playerOneLabel;
    self.player1Score = cell.playerOneScoreLabel;           
    self.player2Name = cell.playerTwoLabel;
    self.player2Score = cell.playerTwoScoreLabel;

    return cell;
}
```

and finally, the tweet setup in the main view controller:

```
- (IBAction)twitter:(id)sender {

    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@, %@-%@", 
                          player1Name.text, player1Score.text, player2Name.text, player2Score.text];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:text];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry"                                                             
                                  message:@"Tweet unsuccessful. Make sure your device has an internet connection and you have a Twitter account."                                                          
                                  delegate:self                                              
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"                                                   
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add tags to each label and then access them via tag through your sender parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly assuming that the cell is rendered / created at the very same time that the user taps on that tweet button.

You could, for example add a tag to the tweet-button that reflects the row index it is shown in.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ScoreListCell";

    ScoreCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    //assign the row-index as a button tag - 
    //NOTE: this misses the way you fetch/create your tweetButton - 
    //      that would have to left to you as you missed to quote 
    //      that part in your sources
    UIButton *tweetButton = ???;

    tweetButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    NSDictionary * dictionary = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.playerOneLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerOneName"];
    cell.playerOneScoreLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerOneScore"];
    cell.playerTwoLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerTwoName"];
    cell.playerTwoScoreLabel.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerTwoScore"];

    return cell;
}
```

Once that button is activated, within the connected action method, you simply fetch that index back from the tag and use it for addressing the correct data within your dictionary.

Note that I left any range checks and further defensive programming actions for you to be done.

```
- (IBAction)twitter:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *tweetButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    unsigned int rowIndex = tweetButton.tag;

    NSDictionary * dictionary = [scoresArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    NSString *playerOneNameText = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerOneName"];
    NSString *playerOneScoreText = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerOneScore"];
    NSString *playerTwoNameText = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerTwoName"];
    NSString *playerTwoScoreText = [dictionary objectForKey:@"playerTwoScore"];

    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
        [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@, %@-%@", 
                          playerOneNameText, playerOneScoreText, playerTwoNameText, playerTwoScoreText];
        [tweetSheet setInitialText:text];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:@"Sorry"                                                             
                                  message:@"Tweet unsuccessful. Make sure your device has an internet connection and you have a Twitter account."                                                          
                                  delegate:self                                              
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"                                                   
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually have the tweet button set up in the  Main controller, linking it to a 'Touch Up Inside' action that's sending the tweet. I'll try out your code and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: In your question you told us that every cell contains a tweet-button. Either I got you wrong or your comment does not make sense.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more explicit. I'm using a storyboard with the dynamic prototype cells. The 4 labels & and the tweet button is inside a prototype cell. I'm declaring the the labels in a separate class and the button in the main controller. I'm able to tweet using this setup, so I'll have to do some experimenting with your code.